# Rails: need to update loaded pages' content updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know Stackoverflow doesn't want discussions, so I will try to ask an answerable question here: basically, I am building a admin area with naught but a table that has a few columns like project name, due date, sort of normal stuff.

But is there a technique that allows non-polling updating of when attribute(s) changes in the server, it gets reflected on the user's loaded page?

The table's data comes from a JSON call to the server, and it gets rendered with some javascript onto the table. Real simple stuff. If you must ask for an example. sure, just a table of first and last names.

```
Homer | Simpson
Lisa  | Simpson
Bart  | Simpson
```

This page is opened on many of our users, then if I change Homer to Remoh, without having the user refresh the page, I want the updated name be, well, updated on the table display.

Does Websocket or the pub/sub pattern have something to do with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a websocket or pub/sub system, exactly as you think.

If this is a Rails application and you're using AJAX stuff -- and it sounds like both things are true -- then your best bet is [Juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), which makes the entire process seamless and easy.

It's relatively painless to use, and the author has a great sample app called [Holla](https://github.com/maccman/holla) that almost solves your problem by itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all changes to the model data to reflect on the admin panel without the need for refreshing the page. That sounds like a job for some simple. AJAX.

In your js.erb file for your admin page, poll for changes every `x` seconds and if the results of that query are different than whats currently being displayed. Update the table's data.

Of course this is limited to how often you are calling the function with `setTimeOut`, but the plus side is that you can tweak that to be just what you like.

If you'd like something more 'out of the box' and more instantaneous. I'd go with @Veraticus's suggestions.

Comment: yeah that's what I want to do, refresh-less updates. But as I mention, I prefer to do with it without polling the server. So I think I'll go with the websocket pub/sub stuff